# How to find the horizontal absolute value in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, operation

I have this code

```
if (@row1) {
            die "Bad format!" if @row1 != @row2;
            my @new = map { abs ($row2[$_] - $row1[$_]) } 0..$#row2;
```

which is resulting the absolute value of row2 -row1.

I tried instead of the abs (row2-row1) to find the absolute value of element 2 -element 1 of the same line of each of all the line, in continuity of upper code. My goal is to obtain the abs(row2 -row1) --> from the new values --> second element -first element of the same line for all the lines.

1 2 3 4

1 4 3 4

1 5 2 3

to become

0 2 0 0

0 1 1 1

which is already done and then to have the final output

2 2 0

1 0 1

So I edited the upper code to:

```
 for ($i=1,$i++,$i>$row){
   my @new1 = map { abs ($row1[$2+$i] - $row1[$1+$i]) } 0..$#row1;
              say join " ", @new1;}
```

but I got "Use of uninitialized value $i in addition". I also substitute $i with "my$i" as well as with "i" and go the same errors. Could someone can explain to me why what I'm trying is wrong?

Comment: your syntax for the c-style for loop is wrong; you have commas where there should be semicolons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my @rows = (
   [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
   [ 1, 4, 3, 4 ],
   [ 1, 5, 2, 3 ],
);

my $num_cols = @{ $rows[0] };

for my $r (1..$#rows) {
   die "Bad format!" if @{ $rows[$r] } != $num_cols;

   my @diffs = map { abs($rows[$r-1][$_] - $rows[$r][$_]) } 0..$num_cols-1;
   my @diff_diffs = map { abs($diffs[$_-1] - $diffs[$_]) } 1..$num_cols-1;
   say "@diff_diffs";
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for the response. I have another question if you don't mind.  Am I in the correct direction, If  I want to keep applying the "horizontal " abs value my @diff_diffs = map { abs($diffs[$_-1] - $diffs[$_]) } 1..$num_cols-1; should I keep changing the diff_diffs to new value and abs($diffs[$_-1] - $diffs[$_] with the abs($PREVIOUS_VALUE_NAME[$_-1] - $PREVIOUS_VALUE_NAME[$_] ?

Comment: If the question needs fixing, edit it and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

One of many possible solutions to the problem

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 0;      # debug flag

my $flag = 1;
my @current;
my @previous;
my @final;

say "First stage";

while( <DATA> ) {
    @current = split ' ';
    if( $flag ) {
        @previous = @current;
        $flag = 0;
        next;
    }
    if( $#current != $#previous ) {
        say "Ops, lines have different number of elements";
        say "Previous: " . join ' ', @previous;
        say "Current: "  . join ' ', @current;
    } else {
        my @data = map { abs($current[$_]-$previous[$_]) } 0..$#current;
        say join ' ', @data;
        push @final, \@data;
    }
    @previous = @current;
}

print Dumper(\@final) if $debug;

say "Second stage";

foreach my $row (@final) {
    my @data = map { abs(@{$row}[$_]-@{$row}[$_+1]) } 0..$#{$row}-1;
    say join ' ', @data;
}

__DATA__
1 2 3 4
1 4 3 4
1 5 2 3
```

Output

```
First stage
0 2 0 0
0 1 1 1
Second stage
2 2 0
1 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer too. Like I asked ikegami  if you dont mind to specify me something. If I want to keep applying the abs after the second stage lets say a third stage should I modify the foreach with if loop and insert a similar to     my @data = map { abs(@{$row}[$_]-@{$row}[$_+1]) } 0..$#{$row}-1; line?

Comment: Your question is not clear on what you would like to do. I add other answer to this post as I assume that probably you want _subroutines_ to do **vertical** and **horizontal** _abs diff_ procedures. Utilization of such subroutines simplifies the code and allows to apply it recursively in the code.

Answer (score 0):

OP's question is not very clear what he wants to do with the data.

My understanding is that he would like to apply **vertical** and **horizontal** *abs diff* recursively.

To simplify processing code, two subroutines was implemented **abs_vdiff** and **abs_hdiff**.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# USAGE:
#   prog.pl
#
# Description:
#   Demonstration code for StackOverflow Q59945359
#
# StackOverflow: 
#   Question 59945359
#
# Author:
#   Polar Bear
#
# Date: Tue Jan 28 13:35:00 PST 2020
#

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $array = read_array();
my $vdiff = abs_vdiff($array);
my $hdiff = abs_hdiff($vdiff);

say "Read array";
show($array);
say "ABS vertical diff";
show($vdiff);
say "ABS horizontal diff";
show($hdiff);
say "We done";

sub read_array {
    my @data;

    while( <DATA> ) {
        my @row = split ' ';
        push @data, \@row;
    }

    return \@data;
}

sub abs_vdiff {
    my $array = shift;
    my @result;

    foreach my $i ( 1..$#{$array} ) {
        my @data = map { abs(@{@{$array}[$i]}[$_]-@{@{$array}[$i-1]}[$_]) } 0..$#{@{$array}[$i]};
        push @result, \@data;
    }
    return \@result;
}

sub abs_hdiff {
    my $array = shift;
    my @data;

    foreach my $row (@{$array}) {
        my @row = map { abs(@{$row}[$_]-@{$row}[$_+1]) } 0..$#{$row}-1;
        push @data, \@row;
    }

    return \@data;
}

sub show {
    my $array = shift;

    foreach my $row ( @{$array} ) {
        say join ' ', @{$row};
    }
}

__DATA__
1 2 3 4
1 4 3 4
1 5 2 3
```

Output

```
Read array
1 2 3 4
1 4 3 4
1 5 2 3
ABS vertical diff
0 2 0 0
0 1 1 1
ABS horizontal diff
2 2 0
1 0 0
We done
```

Comment: Thanks again for the response. First of all, I want to come clean that your initial post answer in my question. I made an extra question to get deep into Perl as my knowledge is basic. Your last post It is almost what I'm asked you for. I asked how should I change the suggested code to keep applying the ABS horizontal diff (as you called it in this case) in order to have one column at the end ...

Comment: Ok, please visit the following [webpage](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/bookshelfs.html) -- I hope that you will find it useful. Also as you learn perl [Beginning Perl](https://www.perl.org/books/beginning-perl/), [Perl library](https://www.perl.org/books/library.html), [Free Perl books](https://www.linuxlinks.com/excellent-free-books-learn-perl/).

Comment: Thank you sooooo much! I really appreciated your help and your time for helping me!